# Get current execution of command out in ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I am running a simulation command in a server using `ssh`, from my terminal.

The simulation is running for 10+ hours. I am expecting output after 15+ hours.

During its execution it was echoing on the terminal some random results. 
What is important to me is the end results that it will generate during last 30 mins. of the simulation before it ends.

I lost Internet connection so my `ssh` broke, but then when I again connected to `ssh`, I checked that my program was still running in the remote server.

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2063 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2064 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
 2156 pts/14   01:19:14 sim-cache
15446 ?        00:00:00 sshd
15448 pts/30   00:00:00 bash
15593 pts/30   00:00:03 sim-cache
15636 ?        00:00:00 sshd
15637 pts/31   00:00:00 bash
15652 pts/31   00:00:00 ps
```

But since it is running in background I will never see its output.

Can someone tell me how can I bring the running process into current terminal, so that whatever this process echoes here after I can see that in the terminal?

Comment: This question should have been asked in Linux and Unix Stack Exchange since there is really no coding help involved here. Although, I did answer it below. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fg` command does that. Here's a [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/) or use `man fg` for help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to start the simulation in [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) that allows disconnecting and attaching from terminals. You can even attach from multiple terminals same time to see output from multiple computers same time.

Answer (score 0):

While it will not help you with the instance that is already running, you can redirect the output of your program to a log file as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26912302/2988730) to a related question:

```
sim-cache > logfile < /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This way, you will have the output regardless of whether you can reconnect to the process before it completes or not.

For the time being, use `fg 2156` to bring the process to the foreground in your shell, where `2156` is the PID of `sim-cache` from the listing you gave.